# WCF Service Reference

Tags: wcf, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

I created a WCF service that works perfectly when I go to `http://localhost:52099/MyPagesWS.svc`

Then I create a test MVC 4 project and add Service Reference with name `ServiceReference1` to that url. When I click "Go" it finds my functions.

But when I try to call it in the code, `ServiceReference1` cannot be called.

Do you have any idea what's going on?

*I created a ConsoleApplication. That works.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this. When you add the service reference, on advanced setting remove the "reuse types" checkbox.